# "Seeking Help with an Error in Implementing Patrick Collins' Automation Smart Contract"

Tags: chainlink-automation

I ran into a problem with implementing Patrick Collins' automation smart contract, and I received "contract 'raffle should be marked as abstract" and is not compiled. What is wrong with my code?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/AutomationCompatible.sol";

error Raffle__NotEnoughEthEnterned();
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__NotOpen();
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatibleInterface {}
```